# Is taking halloween pictures for school shirk?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, shirk, tawba, holidays

So I’m in this class where we had a project to teach children English. The topic was halloween. We had this event where they learnt halloween vocabulary and they gave me the task to take pictures of the event. Does that mean that I’m supporting it? I know that halloween is like a shirk holiday, but I’m not sure if what I did is shirk as well. Also I was aware of the fact that it’s most likely sinful but I still took the pictures and sent them to my teacher.

Answer (score 0):

It is halal to make a documentary on a pagan rite as it is halal to make a documentary on a criminal organisation etc.

Hence it is not necessary to discuss whether the practice of Halloween which originated in a shirk practice but is now no more practiced in this sense is shirk or an other form of haram action: We may talk about it in a documentary style.